# simple ember.js app - why does the model data not appear in view?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm currently trying to learn ember.js framework. I have a VERY simple app, using the starterkit as a starting point.

app.js file contains:

```
// Application
var App = Em.Application.create();

// Models
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    fName: null,
    surname: null
});

// Controller
App.personController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    init: function(){
        // create an instance of the person model
        var person = App.Person.create({
        fName: 'Fred',
        surname: 'Bloggs'
    });
    this.pushObject(person);
    }
});
```

And my `index.html` is based on the default boiler plate:

```
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#each App.personController}}
        <p>{{fName}} {{surname}}</p>
    {{/each}}
  </script>


  <!-- The missing protocol means that it will match the current protocol, either http or https. If running locally, we use the local jQuery. -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-0.9.8.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

When I check in the browser, I see no js errors, and the rendered html shows the handlebars are rendering, but with no content.

```
<div id="ember163" class="ember-view">
    <script id="metamorph-0-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script><script id="metamorph-0-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
</div>
```

Any help or explanation as to why nothing is rendered is greatly appreciated. I would have thought that the init function would have rendered a single user

Regards,

Martin

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with your code (and `this._super();`) showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/pjmorse/TFUA4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the App as a global namespace, without the var:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/GhBfn/

As @Jimmy write, don't forget to call `_super()` in the init method.

Comment: Thanks for your swift responses. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `this._super()` before declaring var person.